# setting rootURL causing 404 error on page refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, router

If I set language as rootURL this works I am able to go to any route/subroute and current language will be present in url, but on page refresh browser is trying get app from that language folder any thoughts? :/ I am using Ember 1.11.

```
// router.coffee

`import Ember from 'ember';`
`import config from './config/environment';`

Router = Ember.Router.extend
  location: config.locationType
  rootURL: '/' + localStorage.getItem('locale') + '/'

// config/environment.js

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    locationType: 'history',
    baseURL: '/'
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `rootURL` for this purpose. Instead, create a route that will be a parent to all other routes:

```
//../app/router.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';
var Router = Ember.Router.extend(
    {
        location: config.locationType
    }
);
Router.map(
    function ()
    {
        this.route(
            'lang', { path: '/:lang' }, function ()
            {
                this.route('index', { path: '/' });
                this.route('404', { path: '/*wildcard' });
                this.route('your-route-name');
            }
        );
    }
);
export default Router;
```

Than you can use `afterModel` method of `lang` route to determine desired locale:

```
//../app/routes/lang.js
import config from '../config/environment';
export default Ember.Route.extend(
    {
        afterModel: function (params)
        {
            var allowedLocales = config.i18n.allowedLocales;
            var defaultLocale = config.i18n.defaultLocale;
            this.set(
                'i18n.locale',
                params && params.lang && allowedLocales.indexOf(params.lang) > -1 ? params.lang : defaultLocale
            );
        }
    }
);
```

And in `index` route you need to detect user's locale from browser's settings or use default one:

```
//../app/routes/index.js
import config from '../config/environment';
export default Ember.Route.extend(
    {
        beforeModel: function ()
        {
            var allowedLanguages = config.i18n.allowedLocales;
            var language = config.i18n.defaultLocale;
            if (navigator.languages) {
                for (let lang of navigator.languages) {
                    if (allowedLanguages.indexOf(lang) > -1) {
                        language = lang;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (navigator.language) {
                    language = navigator.language;
                } else {
                    if (navigator.userLanguage) {
                        language = navigator.userLanguage;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.transitionTo('lang.index', { lang: language });
        }
    }
);
```

BTW, your Ember version is quite old. You may want to upgrade it to 1.13 (1.13.x shouldn't break your app, 2.x could).

Comment: Thx I am doing something like this now, but requires a lot of changes I need to change all link-to helpers, then `transitionTo`, `transitionToRoute`, `modelFor`, and after all that I need to ensure in every route that url is correctly updated because if I change language to russian (which will refresh the page)from the page from `your-route-name` for example I will still have `en.your-route-name` in url after refresh :/

Comment: `this.transitionTo('lang.index', { lang: language });` Could you pls explain why this line cannot be just string this way I have infinite loop only works if I do this `this.transitionTo('lang.index', language );`

Comment: @varto I copied that code from my blog post which I made at 2015-07-19. It worked back then. Unfortunately, can't check now. Probably api was changed. According to most recent ember docs, `this.transitionTo('lang.index', language );` is correct.

Comment: thx so just last question url is updated only when I change language from index route if I go further in journey across the app, and try to change language url in some nested route then will not be updated with that new `:lang`. Is there any way to always update dynamic param `:lang`. Even if I try add redirect to the same route in `beforeModel` hook that will work only for routes which dont have dynamic params already

Comment: How do you try to change language? Updating url in browser or via some code?

Comment: Basicaly just sending selected language to backend, and updating locale ` setLocale: (locale) ->
      @set('defaultSelection', Ember.copy(locale))
      Ember.$.ajax(
        url: "#{@get('ENV.apiBaseURL')}locales/#{@get('defaultSelection.shortName')}",
        method: 'PUT',
        success: (data) =>
          localStorage.setItem('locale', @get('defaultSelection.shortName'))
          window.location.reload()`

Comment: @varto I see. the problem is that you need to replace locale in url, not just reload, because url controls locale. The easiest way would be to replace locale in `window.location.href` and redirect user to new url.

Comment: thx man ! so something like this `window.location.href = '#' + this.get('locale')` ?

Comment: @varto I suggest to get current url (`window.location.href` contains full url), find and replace locale using string's replace method and then redirect: `window.location.href = newURL`. Such method will work on any page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148516/discussion-between-varto-and-gennady-dogaev).